# Run multiple sites on the same GWT application

Tags: gwt, configuration

Can someone please point me to the right direction.

I need to be able to host my GWT application in a way that it allows multiple clients to use the same application which could be separated by url's but internally using the same application.

the different sites would probably be seperated by different configurations. eg. different database, different log path etc, etc,

any ideas.?

Comment: Do you mean running one server per client each running the same GWT application or one server with one GWT application accessed by multiple clients (be it through multiple url's)?

Comment: I mean running multiple clients on the same server separated by url's only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully achieved this by setting up separate directories in tomcat for different clients and then creating soft-links to the main application within that folder. when it comes to database connection properties and other configuration properties, instead of pointing them to the main application I just created them separately.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following way to arrange your projects :
- my.application.core.project : it holds all the business logic and views for the application except for the entry point
-my.application.customerX.project : it holds only the entry point and the property files used for having the connection to the db, probably customerX specific theme
-my.application.customerY.project : it holds only the entry point and the property files used for having the connection to the db, probably customerY specific theme

Such an organization of the projects would allow you to have a common core that is distributed to each of the customers and also the ability to build on top of the core customer-specific impelementations.

Comment: thanks. but i dont want to be editing code while in production. i want some way by which i just need to add an additional configuration and create a new suburl for the new client to start working. without editing the actual application.

Answer (score 0):

The url's per client can be done with URL rewriting. Be it with an apache server in front of your application and/or in combination with a Filter in your web application.

As for the configuration, logging, and/or database per client you want a solution that doesn't store a file per client on the file system next to your application. Preferable you store client specific settings in one database and have an admin interface to manage it. For the client's data you also don't want a separate database per client, because it doesn't scale well, and would be a maintenance mess if you need to upgrade your application and databases to a newer version. Look for a multitenant architecture.

I admit this is a vague answer, but without specific system and software descriptions it's kind of hard to give a concrete answer. Nevertheless I hope this answer does give you some direction.